# Can we overlay the file to our custom path

Tags: aem

Can we overlay the file to our custom path or we have to overlay the file to exact folder structure location as in libs?

For example, I want to overlay the `constants.js` (`/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/constants.js`) file, in this adobe recommended Copy this file to `/apps/cq/ui/widgets/source/constants.js` for overlaying, but in my project that folder structure is not there, so I have copied to the custom path in apps folder and tested the changes and overlaying is working fine.

Comment: I dont understand what your question is. do you want to know if what you did is the right way of overlaying a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file needs to have the same path as the one in libs except for replacing 'libs' with 'apps'. It does not work with custom paths*. If the project does not already have the structure, you can always create it. Don't forget to update the META-INF/Vault/filter.xml file to register the new path with projects package definition.

*Technically you can change the configs to add new searchpaths. But do remember that you might have to share the AEM instance with different tenants  and sticking to the usual conventions goes a long way in having a predictable setup. I honestly don't see a reason to do this, it is already an acceptable practice to overlay under '/apps'. The filters on package provide enough flexibility to get along with other tenants while modifying similar areas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create the overlay in your custom project under ***/apps***. If my assumption is correct, then you can certainly do it.

Taking your example in consideration, `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/constants.js` can be overlayed to `/apps/<your-project>/cq/ui/widgets/source/constants.js` by adding an entry in the **Apache Sling Resource Resolver Factory** configuration.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56193191/7920195) for the detailed steps. I hope this helps.